# MYSQL PHP add table values as rows

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I am trying to join 2 MySQL tables, but I can't manage to help myself using the examples online.

The table `dat_eb_field_values` countains 3 rows: registrant_id, field_id and field_value.

My second table: `dat_eb_registrants` contains normal rows such as user_id, first_name, last_name ect.

I am trying to get those 2 tables together so that the row: field_value can be used just like the other values from `dat_eb_registrants`.

Currently I am using the following method, but since the query's are not connected, I can't sort the output on field_value from the table `dat_eb_field_values`.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT user_id,first_name,last_name,email FROM `dat_eb_registrants`") 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT field_value FROM field_values WHERE (field_id = 53) AND (user_id = $row[0])"); $r1 = mysql_fetch_row($result1); echo $r1[0];
    echo $row[2];
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT field_value FROM dat_eb_field_values WHERE (field_id = 54) AND (user_id = $row[0])"); $r2 = mysql_fetch_row($result2); echo $r2[0];
}
```

end so on....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just use a join?  Try the following query:

```
SELECT users.user_id, users.user_name, users.user_email, field_values.field_value 
FROM users LEFT JOIN field_values ON users.user_id=field_values.user_id
```

You can also append a WHERE clause on the back of that too, such as:

`WHERE field_values.field_id='53'`

If you need some more explainations on JOIN, refer to this great answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5874895/586859

When you run this, you can just loop through your results as normal, but all of your values should be contained in one spot.

Comment: i mean that the table goes on... the id's i gave were just a few of the entire table...

Comment: That's why I put the `WHERE` clause following the initial query - just to inform that it will work perfectly fine if you need to include it in a specific instance.

Comment: ok, so i tried that, but it gives an error saying: 'Could not query: not unique table/alias: 'field_values'' any idea what went wrong?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with you changing the names of your tables in your original question. Make sure you change the names of the tables in the query I provided and check the spelling. The concept works and if you need to add another join (for a third table to query), just append it using the same method and update the table  names.

Comment: ok ,you might have just saved part of my life :) but how can i now echo these because formerly i used '$row[0], $row[1], ect.' for the data in `users`, and for the data in `field_values`, i made new query's. is there a way to have the '$row[3]' data continue using the data from `field_values`? thanks.

Comment: If works exactly the same. For example, if you are using a `while` loop to loop through each row (your query result), just use `$row[i]` where `i` = your column number, or use `$row['column_name']` where `column_name` = the name of the column. In my answer, this can appear as: `$row['user_id']`, `$row['user_name']`, `$row['field_value']` etc..  If you use a `join`, the the column will be added to your result in the order it is placed in your query. In my answer, your search result would dump the following columns respectively: 'user_id', 'user_name', 'user_email', 'field_value'.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select * from users join field_values using( user_id ) where field_id in (53,54);
```

Comment: the tables go on, my example is just a small part of the entire table, so 53 and 54 are simple 2 out of 1232 records..

Comment: Either way - it's an example of how to join and select a subset of it.

Answer (score 0):

[JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) can help you here:

`SELECT u.user_id,u.user_name,u.user_email,f.field_value FROM users u LEFT JOIN field_values f ON f.field_id=u.user_id`

This is assuming that `field_id` matches `user_id`

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is something like this

```
select u.*, v1.field_value as field_53, v2.field_value as field_54 
from users u 
join values as v1 on v1.user_id = u.user_id AND v1.field_id = 53 
join values as v2 on v2.user_id = u.user_id AND v2.field_id = 54;
```

Though it's a double join and it's quite horrid I believe...

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, the `INNER JOIN` is undoubtedly what you're after and its looking like a double join.

To speed up whatever result you go for make sure that you index the columns upon which you are joining. This can change a 30sec query into a .3sec one.