# MySQL Search Over Multiple Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm in the midsts of constructing some database tables, but a possible search issue has just come to mind.

The two tables in question are Genres, a 2 column table holding a list of music genres identified by an ID field, i.e. 1 = Dance, 2 = Rock, and so on. And a Music table, a multi column table with Title, Artist, and Genre_ID fields. And yes you've guest it, Genre_ID refers to the ID of the Genre table.

My question is, if I have a search box on the site powered by PHP, and that search box queries the key fields, so Title, Artist, and Genre to yeld the best result, how can I get that to function correctly in a search, when the Genre name itself is in a separate table, and not in the Music table.

An example search would be, "rock music by ACDC".

Comment: if you're doing that kind of natural free-form search, you'd better be using a fulltext index. and since indexes can't span across tables, you'll have to conduct TWO separate fulltext searches and `union` the results.

Comment: Join the two tables and then search, or create a view that joins them and search the view.

Comment: Join seems to be the way, possibly using view as well. Both Santhos and Bill's answers below put me on the right track. But should I create a view or just search a joined table? And do either support Full text searches.

Comment: You cannot use fulltext search on views, see my answer. I did an update.

Answer (score 1):

Create a view where you join both of the tables. Then use SELECT with LIKE in WHERE clause or better use a fulltext search to do the searching job.

**The view**

```
create view ViewMusicWithGenre as
select "*"
from Music as m
left join Genre as g on m.genre_id = g.id;
```

**Search option with like**

```
select "*"
from ViewMusicWithGenre
where Title like '%<what_you_search>%'
  or Artist like '%<what_you_search>%'
  or Genre like '%<what_you_search>%';
```

I wrote the asterisk in "" because I KNOW that you WILL NOT use an asterisk.
Left join is there because you want the row even without specified genre (very likely).

**The fulltext search**

This usually depends on the database you use. This is for instance Microsoft SQL Server 2014:

Fulltext search - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx

Fulltext index - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx

Querying fulltext search - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx

**EDIT: for MySQL database**

MySQL does not support fulltext indeces on views. So you are left with couple of choices:

- use the LIKE statement - *could be ineffective, also more work later on*
- create the fulltext index on Music table and omit the genre - *not good enough*
- create a new table that resembles the join and fill it on say daily basis with a job (or something like that) a do the fulltext search on that table - *best solution in long terms, but more work to begin with and includes data duplicity*

You also have to bear in mind that fulltext indeces only work on MyISAM storage engine.

**The create statement for the joint table**

```
create table fulltextSearchTable (
    Music_ID int not null primary key,
    Music_Title varchar(1024) not null,
    Music_Artist varchar(1024) not null,
    Genre_ID int not null,
    Genre_Title varchar(1024) not null,
    fulltext(Music_Title, Music_Artist, Genre_Title)
) engine=MyISAM;
```

**The select with fulltext search**

```
select "*"
from fulltextSearchTable
where match(Music_Title, Music_Artist, Genre_Title) against ('your_keyword');
```

Comment: Thanks Santhos. I'll be using MySQL in a Linx (CentOS 6) box. Database won't be massive at first, but does have the prospect of growing over time.

Comment: I used to work with MySQL databases but that were the times I did not not anything about fulltext search, so this is what I found:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 1):

To connect multiple tables in a query, you should look at using "join" statements. Rather than reinventing the wheel, the first answer to this post does a good job of explaining them... [When to use a left outer join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874733/when-to-use-a-left-outer-join)

Comment: Ah, that seems so simple when you look at that example. Genius. But can you then do a full text search on that join?

Answer (score 0):

You can try **INNER JOIN** like this:

```
$result=mysqli_query($YourConnection,"SELECT music.title, music.artist FROM music 
INNER JOIN genres ON music.genre_id=genres.genre_id
WHERE music.title LIKE '$searchword'
OR music.artist LIKE '$searchword'
OR genres.genre LIKE '$searchword'");
```

And then print the results like this:

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['title']." - ".$row['artist']."<br>";
}
```